# MSSql - Implicit & Explicit Identity INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, uniqueidentifier, sql-insert

The question is:

**Is there a way to specify both implicit & explicit Identities in the same `INSERT` ?**

```sql
INSERT INTO target (id, name)
VALUES
  (1, 'machin')
, (2, 'chouette')
, (3, 'trutruc')
, (NULL, 'chouchouette')
, (NULL, 'chose')
;
```

Or do I have to make 2 distinct queries ?

Please checkout [my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cfd90/3)

---

Context: I'm presenting an inline editor for this list to the user in which he can create/update/delete values. When he submits it I'm replacing the values. As these value are related to other objects, I'm trying to keep their ids as much as possible.

Comment: If you find yourself caring about the actual values assigned in an `IDENTITY` column, you're probably using them wrong. They should just be opaque blobs that happen to be a handle to a unique row.

Comment: The context is I'm editing this entire list while trying to keep ids for related objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to use separate queries. To even insert into the `IDENTITY` column, you have to turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` `ON` - at which point, you're telling the server "trust me, I'll provide appropriate values".

I tried constructing a query that used `IDENT_CURRENT` and computed the identity values for your `NULL` ones, but there's no guarantee on how many times the `IDENT_CURRENT` is called and what values it will return, so it's difficult to produce results identical to what the server would have produced under normal circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for answering the original question (No :). So you are suggesting I should `UPDATE` the values for which I have an id and `INSERT` the others, seems logical indeed.

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY - yes, although you might want to consider [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

Comment: Ho I didn't know this one, seems very interesting

Answer (score 0):

> When he submits it I'm replacing the values.

That is called a serious programming mistake.

The issue is that an Identity is an identity and if you delete / insert instead of updating you make sure you can never use referential integrity. s RI is a core fundamental of having good data - this approach is seriously cunterproductive.

The main problem here is not "inserting with specific value" but "why make an insert instead of an update".